# View-users permissions only view some users

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to grant a user the permission to view only some (not all) users of the realm?
example:
we have user_1 and group_1, group_2. user_1 can see members of group_1 but can't see members of group_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would need to enable [fine grained permissions](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_fine_grain_permissions) feature (`admin_fine_grained_authz`). See the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#profiles) on how to do this.

And then you will need to configure your policies and permissions according to your needs. In your case, you need to allow the right/scope `view-members` for `user_1`  on resource `group_1`.